# How can I make lein ring / jetty server accessible externally?

Tags: clojure, compojure

I'm currently attempting to start a project with Compojure.

At this point I am just trying to run the hello world app and see it through the browser.

I have a droplet on Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 13.04 installed and I cannot seem to access the webpage once the server is started.

```
lein ring server-headless 3000

eg: http://hostname:3000
```

I just get page not found. I checked to make sure jetty is using port 3000 and it is.

Am I missing dependencies?

I can't think of anything that would prevent me from viewing the page.

**Update: **
If I run the server on port 80 I can see it. I haven't added or configured any firewalls unless the Digital Ocean image comes with one by default.

Comment: could you expand on the error message a bit? Is it "connection refused" "connection timed out" or a 404 "page not found" error?

Comment: Do you have port 3000 open on the droplet? Can you get the instance to run on port 80? Consider making an uberwar (with the lein ring uberwar task) and having tomcat serve that as a servlet (this is how I usually deploy webapps, and it works).

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt the connection is timing out.

Comment: @noisesmith I don't have any firewall installed, so 3000 should be open.

Comment: @noisesmith It runs on port 80... Is there a firewall included in ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/port-not-listening-for-outside-connections I found this recommendation for seeing which ports you have open on digital ocean. Also try `wget localhost:3000` from inside the digital ocean shell to see if it is accessible there.

Answer (score 0):

on the instance run

```
 sudo netstat -np | grep 3000
```

to see what address your server is listening to, if it is `0.0.0.0` then your server is listening to connections from any source and the problem is with an upstream firewall (most likely) or a local firewall (unlikely). If it is '127.0.0.1`or`::1/128` then your server is only listening for local connections and you need to change the binding address in the project.clj file, though this is unlikely as binding to any interface by default

Comment: It is not binding to an IP address. When I changed the port of the server to 80 I was able to see it.

Comment: every listening socket in any unix based system has a "bound address" this is either localhost (127.0.0.1) meaning that it will only accept connections that arrive bound to the address 127.0.0.1, or it's some specific address for one of the network interfaces in which case it will listen to connections arriving on that interface, or it's 0.0.0.0 which is an alias for any interface.

Comment: if you can make it listen on port 80 that indicates that the bound address is 0.0.0.0 and you need to allow access to port 3000 on that instance in the configuration for the providers firewall.

Comment: You can check that it's running on the digitalocean instance by running `curl http://localhost:3000`